# Making an Array that stores pairs and or a class in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, inheritance, overloading

I've looked for a while and none of the answers seem to fully fit my question, that or I've just hit a mental barrier.

I've made a class that has set and get methods and an output method called pairs, this works with two ints x+y and they each have set and get methods individually. I need to make a dynamic array based on the code below that can store these pairs. I'm not looking to be spoon fed I just want to know if my logic is correct and be pointed in the right direction.

```
class dynArray //a dynamic(ish) array class

{

public:

  dynArray() : data(0), sz(0) { }

  dynArray(int size) : sz(size) { data = new int[sz]; }

  virtual ~dynArray() { if(data) delete [] data; } //destructor method

  int& operator [] (int idx) { return data[idx]; } //operator overload!

  int size() { return sz; }

private:

  int * data;

  int sz;

};
```

Pairs class

```
class pairs{
public:
  pairs() : x(0), y(0) { }
  void setX(int);
  void setY(int);
  void outputXY(int, int);
  int getX();
  int getY();
private:
  int *x;
  int *y;
};

void pairs::setX(int a)
{
    x = &a;
}
void pairs::setY(int b)
{
    y = &b;
}
int pairs::getX()
{
    return *x;
}
int pairs::getY()
{
   return *y;
}

void pairs::outputXY(int c, int d)
{
    x = &c;
    y = &d;

    cout << "Number 1:" << c << "  Number 2:" << d;
}
```

I'm very rusty with c++ so my logic has just vanished, I'm struggling to see how I would make an array that can store two ints within one element. Then i thought maybe I could make the pair class an array that stores two numbers in element 0 and 1 and then make an array of that class using the dynamic code, figuring out how to do this has stumped me though. All I really need is a helpful link or terms to be thrown at me as I really want to learn the code myself. Any help would be really appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason your pairs class is storing pointers to the ints rather than storing them by value?

Comment: Start with not storing pointers to parameters. (Your `pairs` class is very confusing.  Why are `x` and `y` pointers *at all*?) To "make an array that can store two ints within one element", make an array of `pairs` instead of `int`.

Comment: In all honesty the inclusion of pointers was purely for practice with pointers, the rest of the pairs class is fairly standard and right though isn't it?

How would I go about making an array of the pairs? I'm confused as to how I would set up the actual array without declaring a data type, I know this is basic stuff so I'm just as annoyed as you will be! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the STL library, in particular [std::pair](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/pair/) and some kind of container like [std::lists](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/) or [std::vectors](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/). In order to implement some own, additional functionality, you may create your own class derived from those.

(Not enough "reputation" to post this answer as comment...)

Comment: Thanks, I haven't covered std::pair yet, I did however see it on other answers, I think a more conventional way is needed. Just to clarify this is third week work that is additional and unmarked so I'm doing this purely for learning and not for an assignment! Vectors are handy though I have used those before, again the only reason I am not using them here is purely to stay on task. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @Marco Then I would directly derive from vector: `class dynArray : std::vector<pairs> {...}`

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood your issue, I'd suggest using a std::vector to store your elements since it will also spare you the memory management hassle

```
class dynArray //a dynamic(ish) array class
{
public:
    dynArray() {}
    dynArray(int size) { data.resize(size); /* Initialize with default-constructed elements */ }
    pairs& operator [] (int idx) { return data[idx]; }
    size_t size(){ return data.size(); }
private:
    std::vector<pairs> data;
};
```

Just provide some insertion methods and you'll be good to go. Notice that the design will greatly simplify itself with the above solution.

Another solution as user236012 pointed out could be to use [std::pair](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/pair/) (specifically `std::pair<int,int>`) and just store the pairs in the vector.

If you intend to use the pairs class, be aware that **your code is wrong**:

```
void pairs::setX(int a)
{
    x = &a; // Address of the actual parameter - address on the stack
}
```

therefore I'd suggest to either store plain values or use `std::pair` as suggested. There's really little point in storing pointers to integer values (they'd even be more expensive on many architectures).

Comment: Thank you, we haven't covered vectors in class yet so I've been cautious about using them within my code. Do you know of a way to do this without using vectors? I'm sorry for the annoyingly basic questions

Comment: @thebeardedranga You could use a normal array of pointers to pairs elements, although I usually wouldn't recommend it

Answer (score 0):

A c-like way:

```
int * getPair(int idx) 
{
  return &data[idx*2]; 
}

void setPair(int idx, int * xy) 
{ 
  data[idx*2]=xy[0]; data[idx*2+1]=xy[1]; 
}
```

Comment: If you need fine control on memory usage, must keep in mind that sizeof struct and classes can be different on different platforms. Fields get aligned to a multiple of sizeof(int), and sizeof(int) can change. Never exchange a array of classes in binary form between machines.